# File size changes after star rating it - Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

I experienced that the size of an image changes after star rating and saving it.
Is this some kind of compression? Does Windows do something to the picture itself? Any ideas?

[image: Before star rating the picture]
[image: After star rating the picture]

Comment: Im sure it adds meta data to the file when you rate it.

Comment: Yes, but adding Meta data should rather increase the file size rather than shrinking it.